# Calculus Limits Problem

Tags: calculus, limits

L'Hopital's Rule is not allowed.

> **Question 1:** 
>   $$\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{\sqrt{6+x}-2}{\sqrt{3+x}-1} =  \ ?$$

I tried to cross multiply $\frac{\sqrt{6+x}-2}{\sqrt{3+x}-1}$with $\frac{\sqrt{3+x}+1}{\sqrt{6+x}+2}$ and I got $x+2$ on both LHS and RHS thus I conclude
$\frac{\sqrt{3+x}+1}{\sqrt{6+x}+2}$ is equal to $\frac {\sqrt{6+x}-2)}{\sqrt{3+x}-1}$.
Thus when I sub $x = -2$ into $\frac{\sqrt{3+x}+1}{\sqrt{6+x}+2}$ I got $0.5$.

> **Question 2:**
>   $$\lim_{x\to \pi} \sin\frac{x+\pi}{x-\pi}\sin\frac{x-\pi}{x+\pi} = \ ?$$

I said that $\sin\frac{x-\pi}{x+\pi}$ tends to $0$.

For $\sin\frac{x+\pi}{x-\pi}$, I use squeeze theorem and said that it can lies between $1$ and $-1$.
Thus, $\sin\frac{x+\pi}{x-\pi}\sin\frac{x-\pi}{x+\pi} = 0$.

Comment: Pretty sure cross multiply is not the right term.  Cross-multiplication is where you have one fraction equaling another and multiply both sides by the product of the denominators.

Answer (score 2):

For real $x, \left|\sin\dfrac{x+\pi}{x-\pi}\right|\le1$

$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\sin\frac{x-\pi}{x+\pi}\sin\dfrac{x+\pi}{x-\pi}$$

$$=0\cdot\text{ a finite real number}=0$$

---

$$\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{\sqrt{6+x}-2}{\sqrt{3+x}-1}=\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{\sqrt{3+x}+1}{\sqrt{6+x}+2}\cdot\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{6+x-4}{3+x-1}$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{3+(-2)}+1}{\sqrt{6+(-2)}+2}\cdot1$$ as $x+2\ne0$ as $x\ne-2$ as $x\to-2$

Comment: Hi, can you explain the answer for the sin ?

Comment: @TBX, Please confirm the edited version of the answer and pinpoint your line of confusion

Comment: The entire expression (x+pie)(x-pie) belongs to sin.

Comment: @TBX, Sorry I could not read the question properly

Comment: My apology if i wasnt clear when posting the question!

Comment: @TBX, all well that ends well :)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

Set $x=-2+y$

$$\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{\sqrt{6+x}-2}{\sqrt{3+x}-1} = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{4+y}-2}{\sqrt{1+y}-1}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{(y/4)+O(y^2)}{(y/2)+O(y^2)}=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y/4}{y/2}=(1/2)$$

Answer 2:

Set $x=\pi+y$

$$\lim_{x\to \pi} \sin\frac{x+\pi}{x-\pi}\sin\frac{x-\pi}{x+\pi} = \lim_{y\to 0} \sin\frac{y+2\pi}{y}\sin\frac{y}{y+2\pi} =I $$

$$|I|=\lim_{y\to 0} \left|\sin\frac{y+2\pi}{y}\right|\left|\sin\frac{y}{y+2\pi}\right|\le \lim_{y\to 0} 1\left|\sin\frac{y}{2\pi}\right|=0$$

So $I=0$